# What is the appropriate place in SE network to seek feedback on a project idea?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have an idea for an open source project. However I do not want to start working on it based solely on my own idea. My own conceptualization of it would make it limited to my particular use case and I myself would likely not see its shortcomings.

I would likely to get community feedback and criticism on it to make it more generic and refine it further.

Should I ask such a question on Stackoverflow, Code Review, Code Golf, or Software Recommendations? Or is there no site on Stackexchange where this is within scope and I should look at some other internet forums?

Comment: [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is more geared towards the "whiteboard problems" programmers may have. It may not be the right place, depending on what exactly your question is and how it's worded, but it might be worth a look. None of the sites you listed besides Stack Overflow would be good places to put your question.

Comment: You could just start an open source project somewhere, state your goal and your ideas and hope for feedback. Programmers.SE might help you find good paths towards a specific goal, but defining which goals are worth to pursue.. no SE site can help you there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don’t believe this would be appropriate on any Stack Exchange site. Stack Exchange is designed not to provide answers to specific people, but to “collectively increas[e] the sum total of *good* programming knowledge in the world”. Questions are intended to be useful to others who come along. Some, like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), might be a little bit of a stretch by this definition, but you can still make it fit: someone looking at the code in the question might see something similar in their codebase and read the answers to see how to improve it. It sounds like the question you want to ask would be useful to you, but would not really contribute to “the sum total of […] knowledge in the world”, so I don’t think it fits on any Stack Exchange site.

That said, [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) would be a good place to ask if you aren’t too bothersome to the inhabitants.